# How to use Session on Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, for-loop

How to use session on google app engine for java .
I have configured the session to enable in the appengine-web.xml.
I use HttpSession.
And I have tested on the local. It's work.
But when I upload the application it's not work.